# Adicionar indice em um laço de arrays

Tags: php, php-7

```
for($i=0; $i<count($produtos); $i++) {
            
            $itens = array(); 

            for($j=0; $j<count($especificacao); $j++) {

                if ($produtos[$i]["produto_id"] === $especificacao[$j]["prod_espeficacao_produto_id"]) {
                    array_push($itens, $especificacao[$j]);
                }          
            }

           array_push($produtos[$i], $itens);
        }
```

Gostaria de adicionar um índice exemplo "teste" nesse lugar marcado na hora do array_push seria possivel ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade ao definir o [$i] no array_push, você já está atribuindo uma chave/índice ao array produtos.

Ex: Na primeira execução do for, onde o $i = 0, ao executar o array_push($produtos[$i], $itens); , você está atribuindo o índice 0 ao seu array, ou seja, para adicionar o índice teste, basta executar o arra_push desta forma:

array_push($produtos['teste'], $itens).

caso prefira, pode adicionar desta forma também:

$produtos['teste'] = $itens;